# How to bring bash history to default in CentOS 7

Tags: bash, centos, history, bashrc, command-history

```
$  set -o | grep history    
    history         on
    $  echo $HISTFILE       
    /root/.bash_history
    $  echo $HISTSIZE
    1000
    $  echo $HISTFILESIZE
    1000
```

I ran following command and history become disabled for all users on logout

```
$  ln -sf /dev/null ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

How can I re-enable history or make it normal as default?

Comment: Other users shouldn't be affected, unless they use the same home directory... or you changed the  /etc/skel files so all new users get the null-linked history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have symlinked `~/.bash_history` file to `/dev/null` which is basically an empty file, void.
To start a new history file just:

```
rm -rf ~/.bash_history
```

The command you have used:

```
ln -sf /dev/null ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

Basically redirects (content of a) file `.bash_history` to a "trash can" (`/dev/null`) but, unlike MS Windows trash can, you won't be able to recover files from there. Then:

```
history -c
```

Clears all the history entries for current user.
Basically, this whole line intends to clear history and throw away any new history entries.

Comment: Should work. `/dev/null` might be more like a *black hole of nothingness* than a trash can.

Comment: @Xen2050 thank you! I couldn't think of the right words to describe it ;)